# Why Webpack's `require.ensure` compiles to `Promise.resolve()` when using ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-2, ts-loader

Using TypeScript (2.3.2) and Webpack 2 with ts-loader and babel-loader.

I'm trying to create a code split for some module but I noticed that my `require.ensure(...)` compiled to `Promise.resolve().then(function(require) {})` and the chunk file is not created.

Example:

(Some .ts file)

```
"use strict";

require.ensure(['./components/MyComp'], function (require) {

    let Comp = require('./components/MyComp');

    console.log(Comp);

}, "myComp");
```

And the compiled code:

```
Promise.resolve().then((function (require) {

    var Comp = __webpack_require__(56);

    console.log(Comp);
}).bind(null, __webpack_require__)).catch(__webpack_require__.oe);
```

Here are some of my settings:

tsconfig.json

```
{
"version": "2.3.2",
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "es7",
        "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
        "webpack-env",
        "inferno"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "removeComments": false
},
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "webpack"
],
"files": [
    "src/index.d.ts"
],
"compileOnSave": false
}
```

webpack.config.js (the modules section)

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
},
```

Any idea why? I tried to go with the implementation at https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/tree/master/test/comparison-tests/codeSplitting but with no success.

Comment: Thanks, it's not the complete version, but I think that the `CommonChunkPlugin` is relevant for multiple entry points for creating vendors file for example.. and not for code splitting

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my last commont because it was nonsens. I should always think before writing ;-). Another try: You  need not (must not?) specify `'./components/MyComp'` in the dependency array if you also `require()` it. That's the only odd thing I see.

Comment: See: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#empty-array-as-parameter

Comment: I'm not much interested in TypeScript but I had a look into the ts-loader codeSpliiting example. There was a module called `require.d.ts` to implement the require.ensure method in type script. Did you add such a script too?

Comment: Yeah, I tried also using `@types/webpack-env`